# Haskell функции на списках по образцу

Tags: функции, списки, haskell

Описание задачи ниже. По моему подходит только process1, но такой ответ неверный. Какие еще функции подходят?

Ниже даны реализации функции process :: (b -> d) -> [(a,b,c)] -> [d], которая принимает в качестве первого аргумента функцию-обработчик, а в качестве второго - список троек. Функция process должна применить обработчик к среднему элементу каждой третьей тройки из списка, считая от его головы. Вернуть эта функция должна список результатов обработки, например

GHCi> process (^2) [(1,1,1),(1,2,1),(1,3,1),(1,4,1),(1,5,1),(1,6,1),(1,7,1)]
[9,36]
Выберите те версии реализации функции process, которые действительно выполняют эту работу на любых списках.

```
process0 f []                       = []
process0 f [t1]                     = []
process0 f (t1 : t2 : (x,y,z) : ts) = f y : process0 f ts

process1 f []                       = []
process1 f (t : [])                 = []
process1 f (t1 : t2 : [])           = []
process1 f (t1 : t2 : (x,y,z) : ts) = f y : process1 f ts

process2 f []                       = []
process2 f (t1 : t2 : (x,y,z) : ts) = f y : process2 f ts
process2 f [t]                      = []
process2 f [t1,t2]                  = []

process3 f [t]                      = []
process3 f (t1 : t2 : (x,y,z) : ts) = f y : process3 f ts
process3 f (t1 : t2 : ts)           = []
process3 f []                       = []

process4 f (t1 : t2 : (x,y,z) : ts) = f y : process4 f ts
process4 f ts                       = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Если ограничиваться только рамками вашей задачи, и тем, что process1 не верный, то тогда подойдет process4:

```
process4 f (t1 : t2 : (x,y,z) : ts) = f y : process4 f ts
process4 f ts                       = []
```

Такая запись более лаконична и не требует дополнительных проверок, соответственно более корректна чем process1, хотя бы условий задачи вы и не указали.

Answer (score 1):

- process0 — не рассмотрен вариант списка двух элементов
- process1 — рассмотрены: пустой, с одним элементом, с двумя, и основной вариант - всё ок
- process2 — рассмотрен пустой, с одним тоже, с двумя тоже, основной есть - всё ок, порядок тут не повлияет
- process3 — рассмотрен список с одним, основной вариант, список двух и более (не попавший в основной), и пустой, т.е. все варианты - всё ок
- process4 — рассмотрен основной вариант и все остальные - всё ок

Т.о. подходят все, кроме process0.

```
λ> let tests n = [[(x, x, x) | x <- [1..l]] | l <- [1..n]]
λ> map (process0 id) (tests 4)
[[],[],*** Exception: <interactive>:3:5-88: Non-exhaustive patterns in function process0
λ> map (process1 id) (tests 4)
[[],[],[],[3],[3]]
λ> map (process2 id) (tests 4)
[[],[],[],[3],[3]]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень странно Вы сформулировали вопрос. Но если я правильно понял то, что Вам нужно, то достаточно написать:

```
takeEvery n list = map snd $ filter ((==0) . (`mod` n) . fst) $ zip [1..] list
process f list = map (\(_, x, _) -> f x) $ takeEvery 3 list
```

Comment: Скорее всего, у ironfrog тестовое задание, и нужно выбрать правильный вариант из предложенных. Поэтому, даже если у вас правильный ответ, автору вопроса это не поможет)